# excel SQL VBA updating 2 access tables

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform

how do I create excel VBA where it will update 1 table while another is going to add data on another table. Below is my code to append a table (tbl_Raw). The new table is tbl_assign with 3 columns. 2 of the column info is located in the code below while the 3rd column is just a time stamp to indicate when it was updated, but placed on another table.

```
    On Error GoTo errHandler

        Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim i As long, X As long
        Dim varr As String

        If Me.labelChild.Caption = "Child Ref #" Then
            MsgBox "You must enter Child Case.", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Insufficent data"
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection 
        varr = Me.labelChild.Caption
        cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "\\10.8.1.62\Chimp Change\Analysis\Database\ChimpDB.accdb"
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
        rs.Open "SELECT Parent_Ref, Child_Ref, Analyst FROM tbl_Raw WHERE Child_Ref = """ & varr & """", ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText

        If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
            MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        With rs
            rs!Analyst = Me.Agents.Value
            rs.Update
        End With

        ImportCasesForm
        Me.lstCases.RowSource = "CasesList"
        MsgBox "Congratulations! The Case has been assigned", vbInformation, "Assign successful"

    CleanUp:
        If Not rs is Nothing then 
            rs.close
            set rs = nothing
        end if
        If Not cnn is Nothing then 
            cnn.close
            set cnn = nothing
        end if  
        Exit Sub

    errHandler:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Load Cases"
        GoTo CleanUp
        End Sub
```

I don't know if I need to do a SUB or just tweak the existing append code to also do add to another table.

Thanks.

Comment: cleaned up your code a little - setting screen updating is generally a cover up for bad performance IMO. You can open another record set to add records to using the rs.edit/rs.update method. You can also use ado method for executing individual SQL statements.

Comment: @DougCoats While the whitespace formatting is useful, some of the other changes should have been comments instead - for example, the code does not include any instance of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (nor the start of the `Sub`!), so we do not know if that is necessary for other reasons: e.g. if there are several shape and/or sheet modifications going on, it's better not to give the user an epileptic fit!  (You should also check `If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then` before you close the `Recordset`, and same for the `Connection`)

Comment: @DougCoats thank you for the modifications. It still works so I'd leave it the way you did. I'm not sure how to proceed with your instructions since I just started coding through excel VBA. can you site examples how to add records with my existing code? thnks

Comment: @Chronocidal The code presented as is has no implications where Application.ScreenUpdating was necessary. If fact the only reference to the application object was getting a label value, which would not cause the epileptic fit. I cant make assumptions based off of under supplied information/details. Also, any kind of code that would be causing those epileptic fits is probably poorly written - interacting with the "applications physical objects" when it most certainly could be done right to begin with. Thanks for the feedback though :)